# VS Code custom editor extension unhelpful error

Tags: typescript, vscode-extensions

I'm trying to write a vscode extension for a customreadonly editor. In testing the code, I get this very unhelpful error. Can someone tell me what I am missing?

```
2022-11-25 11:36:17.198 [error] Activating extension vscode-samples.cat-customs failed due to an error:
2022-11-25 11:36:17.219 [error] Error: 
    at O._loadCommonJSModule (../../../vs/workbench/api/worker/extensionHostWorker.js:82:67509)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at m._activate (../../../vs/workbench/api/worker/extensionHostWorker.js:72:8305)
    at m._waitForDepsThenActivate (../../../vs/workbench/api/worker/extensionHostWorker.js:72:8247)
    at m._initialize (../../../vs/workbench/api/worker/extensionHostWorker.js:72:7611)
```

Note: I am using vscode.dev, and this is intended for a web extension.

Comment: Consider using insiders version of VSCode, I guess it may have better errors

Comment: Or the one made for developers I dunno

Answer (score 0):

VSCode has a 'Toggle Developer Tools' command available from the Command Pallet.

The 'Developer Tools' window is effectively the same as you see for a browser. From here you should be able to get better diagnostics.

Given the `Promise.all` error text you are seeing, you may have a network or security problem.

Comment: What about `Promise.all` makes you think I have a "network or security problem"? Also, I do my editing in vscode.dev so the Toggle Developer Tools is not available for me.

Comment: @AdamRaichu I was simply guessing because I agree with you that the error message unhelpful so we're left with nothing else to go with. You will possibly get quicker help if you amend your question with all relevant information such as using vSCode.dev. Perhaps the extension you're developing is also specifically for VSCode dev?